# Find the average speed and velocity of the object

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, velocity, speed

An object travels 11 m north and then turns around and travels 25 m south. If the total time of travel is 52 s what is the average speed and velocity of the object.

I used the formula I was told

average speed = distance/time

11+25m= 36m

36m/52 s = 0.692 s is the answer I calculated but my textbook says its **36/52 s = 9/13**

average velocity  = displacement/time

11-25=14m

14m/52 s = 0.269 s is the answer I calculated but its still wrong

**14m/52 s = 7/26 is the answer**

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong

Comment: Learn to do some math without the calculator. Seriously. You'll be better for it.

Comment: I wasn't told to find the answer without a calculator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that 9/13 is approximately 0.692. You used decimals, the book used fractions.